# Variable for While loop not being recognized as initialized

Tags: c++, variables, visual-studio-2013, while-loop

I am trying to use a variable as the parameter for my `while` loop, like shown below.

```
int compChoice;
while (compChoice < 8){

        compChoice = rand() % 8 + 0;
        cout << compChoice;
    }
```

My goal is to have a random number generated until an 8 is the output. The issue is that my compiler (visual studio pro 2013) is telling me the variable is not initialized. I removed the `while` loop and left the variable there and retried, and the compiler then told me the variable `compChoice` is unreferenced. I also tried just using the last two lines and it worked perfectly. I think I'm doing something wrong with the argument, but I can't figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where in your code do you give `compChoice` a value before you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` condition is reading the contents of `compChoice` before you have assigned `compChoice` a value.  Consider using a do-while loop instead, which will execute the loop body once before checking the condition:

```
int compChoice;
do {
    compChoice = rand() % 8;
    cout << compChoice;
} while (compChoice < 8);
```

However, this won't even work as you desire it to because `rand() % 8` is *guaranteed to be less than 8* by the definition of the modulus operation.  As you have written your code, the loop will never terminate (unless the uninitialized value in `compChoice` is already less than 8 when it is first read).

Perhaps you meant `rand() % 9` or `rand() % 8 + 1`?  But this doesn't even make sense, as it's just an expensive way to assign 8 to `compChoice`.  It seems like you need to take a step back and figure out what you are even trying to do here.

Comment: @m_callens value of that `int` and behavior of your program is undefined. That includes value of 0.

Comment: ***do uninitialized int variables not get defaulted to 0*** For local variables this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @m_callens Uninitialized local variables do not have any predefined value. Technically, reading from an uninitialized local variable causes **undefined behavior**.  The program could do anything -- crash, never finish executing, email your mother, or proceed with some arbitrary number (which might indeed be zero). The behavior might change each time you run the program.

Comment: @m_callens "do uninitialized int variables not get defaulted to 0?" No, they do not.

Comment: ok thats what I thought but was confused when this test case worked, my mistake

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes undefined behavior does something that you expect.

Comment: Which is why you always pay attention to compiler warnings. The compiler can't catch all undefined behavior, but when it does, you listen.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I realize now that the compiler was telling me the variable was uninitialized, As for what I'm trying to do, this was just a bit of a learning experiment. All I really needed was a number generator that roughly approximates a random number from one to eight.

Comment: @RileyMuscha If that's all you need then you just want `int compChoice = rand() % 8 + 1`, no loops required. (Note that the random distribution will not be uniform with this approach.)

Comment: The loop was exclusively for the purpose of making the number keep generating to make sure I had it written properly. I am using the random number generator as a way to make a random choice from an nine value array. (I have already changed the code to reflect nine possibilities instead of eight)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, your program will never end.

```
 rand() % 8;
```

generates numbers between 0 and 7. So you need:

```
rand() % 8 + 1;
```

to generate numbers between 1 and 8.

Also, you will need to initialize rand with:

```
#include <ctime>
```

and:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

before the random generation, and

```
int compChoice=0;
```

before the loop

Comment: really they should ditch `rand` and start using `<random>`

Comment: Ah thanks, that solved a problem I didn't realize I had yet.

Comment: glad I helped you

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `compChoice` before you use it in the loop. So, it has an undefined value.